# Как удалить параметр в url запросе?

Tags: node.js, http, sails.js

Я хочу удалить часть параметра в `url` после того как код был выполнен.
Так выглядит код если не удалять параметр: 
`http://localhost:1337/check?domain=fb.com&success=task&success=note`

Но нужно что бы выглядело так : 
`http://localhost:1337/check?domain=fb.com&success=task`

Это часть кода где добавляется redir:

```
switch (product){
            case 'vc' : 
                createType(vcOwnerId,vcOwnerStatus,"hs_lead_status",companyId,note,name).then(item=>res.redirect(req.body.redir+`&success=${item}`))
                break;
            case 'vd':
                createType(vdOwnerId,vdOwnerStatus,"vc_debt_status",companyId,note,name).then(item=>res.redirect(req.body.redir+`&success=${item}`))
                break;
            case 'sf':
                createType(sfOwnerId,sfOwnerStatus,"secondary_fund_lead_status",companyId,note,name).then(item=>res.redirect(req.body.redir+`&success=${item}`))
                break
    }
```

Comment: используйте https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/url.html вместо `req.body.redir+'&success=${item}'`

Comment: @nörbörnën это сломает код. Я работаю с парусами